# IntentFilter cannot receive Serializable but works for String

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, serializable

I've got a Serializable like this:

```
public class Main implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5053412967314724078L; 
    private ArrayList<Carte> main = new ArrayList<Carte>();


    public Main() {}
    public Main(Carte[] cartes) {
        for (Carte carte:cartes) {
            this.main.add(carte);
        }
    }
    public Carte[] getMain() {
        return (Carte[]) main.toArray();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Carte carte : main) {
            result += carte.toString() + " ";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I send the serializable as extra of an intent:

```
Carte[] cards = ...// Which is initialized elsewhere and been checked, there's no problem with that.
Main mainSerial = new Main(cards);
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction("coinchutc.RECUP");
broadcast.putExtra("cards", mainSerial);
Log.d("JoueurAgent", "Sending broadcast " + broadcast.getAction() + " " + mainSerial.toString());
context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

In the Log I can print out the debug message correctly, that is to say I've successfully constructed the serializable.

Then I try to receive the intent but with no success:

In the onCreate() of the destination Activity I've done:

```
IntentFilter recupFilter = new IntentFilter();
recupFilter.addAction("coinchutc.RECUP");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, recupFilter);
```

I've created the BroadcastReceiver class to receive the broadcast:

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("RejoindrePartieActivity", "receive");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("RejoindrePartieActivity", "Receive action " + action);
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("coinchutc.RECUP")) {
            Log.d("RejoindrePartieActivity", "RECUP");
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Main main = (Main) extras.getSerializable("cards");
                //String recup = extras.getString("cards");
                Log.d("RejoindrePartieActivity", "Receive " + main.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it receives nothing. Even the first Log is not printed.

Then I changed the serializable to a simple string. It all worked!
So I would like to know if I got the serializable right, why the intentfilter cannot even receive the intent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntentFilter recupFilter = new IntentFilter();
recupFilter.addAction("coinchutc.RECUP");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, recupFilter);
```

Above code Must call before `sendBroadcast()`. Call it before you sending Intent.

---

After some clarification from SO-

```
Carte class also needs to be `Serializable` and this does work.
```

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake, the register I've done in the onCreate of the Activity so it is already called before the sendBroadcast(). Besides, a string message can arrive successfully.

Comment: `Main mainSerial = new Main(main);` why and what you are passing in constructor? This is not defined in code?

Comment: Oh, thank you for your remark, I forgot to paste it. Anyway it is not important. I can already print out the constructed serializable object

Comment: If `Carte` is your class then serialize that class too.

Comment: Excuse me, I'd like to know more detail. Where should I serialize Carte?

Comment: Nothing to do more. add in that class `implements Serializable` thats it.

Comment: Just curious, your name looks very familiar to me. Have you participated in Google Summer of Code for KDE?

Comment: No. I was not there :(. But wish to be there

Comment: Ok, I guess there's a person with the same name :)